# htaccess redirect GET request

Tags: .htaccess

I try to redirect some URL with `GET` request to the new URL with `htaccess`.

**old:**
`http://example.com/?screenshot=file%20name.jpg`

**new:**
`http://example.com/downloader.php?screenshot=file%20name.jpg`

I checked similar questions but couldn't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in top of .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} screenshot=(.*)
RewriteRule ^\/$ /downloader.php [QSA,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

or check this modified rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} screenshot=(.*)
RewriteRule ^\/$ /downloader.php?screenshot=%1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I try the second rule but after redirection screenshot parameter always is empty